# Why doesn't this work? It should be a pendulum with harmonic movement

Tags: pstricks, draw, fp

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=0pt,pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-coil,pstricks-add}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}

\FPset\CoilArm{0.25}
\FPset\CoilWidth{0.3}
\FPeval\CoilTurn{round(50/3:3)}
\FPeval\DeltaY{0.5}
\FPeval\Amp{1.5}
\FPeval\FPS{25}
\FPeval\Vx{2}% propagation speed
\FPeval\Period{1}% second

\psset
{
    coilarm=\CoilArm,
    coilwidth=\CoilWidth,
}


\newcommand\System[4][0]{% #1: frame, #2: x, #3: y, #4: label
    \uput[90](#2,4.25){#4}
    \FPeval\CoilHeight{round((4-(#3)-2*CoilArm)/(CoilWidth*CoilTurn):3)}
    \pszigzag[coilheight=\CoilHeight,linejoin=2](#2,4)(#2,#3)
    \ifnum#1=1
        \bgroup
            \psset{origin={#2,#3}}
            \psframe[dimen=inner,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=black](-0.5,0)(0.5,-1)
            \psdot[linecolor=yellow](0,-0.5)
        \egroup
    \fi
}

\begin{document}
\FPeval\DeltaTime{round(1/\FPS:2)}
\FPeval\TotalFrame{round(\FPS*\Period:0)}
\multido{\n=0.00+\DeltaTime}{\TotalFrame}{%
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](-1.5,-2)(3.5,5)
    % Ceiling
    \psframe
    [
        fillstyle=vlines,
        hatchsep=2pt,
        hatchwidth=0.5\pslinewidth,
        hatchcolor=gray,
        hatchangle=45,
        %linestyle=none
    ](0,4)(2,4.25)
    % Spring without box
    \FPeval\Y{round(-DeltaY-Amp*cos(2*pi*\n/Period)+2:3)}
    \System[1]{1}{\Y}{A}
    \psplot[algebraic,linecolor=red,plotpoints=1000]
        {-1.5}{3.5}{-\DeltaY-\Amp*cos((2*\psPi/\Period)*((-\Vx*\n+x-1)/\Vx))+2-0.5}
\end{pspicture}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It compiles with `xelatex`, albeit it's a bit long.

Comment: Works for me. I see the motion when scrolling through the PDF in a PDF viewer using PgDwn/PgUp.

Comment: cant use it in overleaf?

Comment: What do you mean by "Doesn't Work"?

Comment: @jaimelopez to get the illusion of movement, you have to download and open the PDF document in a PDF viewer and then scroll through the pages.

Comment: And how can I keep the single image of the pendulum without movement?

Comment: By not pressing PageUp or PageDown? The PDF you have produced is nothing more than a [flip book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip_book).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to convert the `pdf` output into an animated `gif` with

```
convert -delay 50 -loop 0 -density 300 -scale 300 -alpha remove test.pdf test.gif
```

[image]

Or use package animate and create an animated pdf.